# How can I solve this list indexing problem?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, indexing

I'm always in a constant fight with python lists. I don't know how I do this but everytime I work with list I'm eventually stucked and I don't know how to solve the problem.

I'm sure that this is a quite simple problem to solve, but I've been trying for one hour and I'm completely stucked.

I want to perform an exponential running average on a pandas.series data called train_data, and then predict the output for the next 20 days (I know that with this model I'm actually going to have a lot of error with long time predictions, but I need to do that model to actually demonstrate it).

This is the code. The error is just a simple

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-40-cd9f9f5581ef> in <module>()
     17   running_mean = running_mean*decay + (1.0-decay)*my_data[pred_idx-1]
     18   run_avg_predictions14.append(running_mean)
---> 19   mse_errors.append((run_avg_predictions14[-1]-my_data[pred_idx])**2)
     20   run_avg_x14.append(date)
     21 

IndexError: list index out of range
```

but I don't know how to solve it.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

window_size14 = 14
pred_len = 20

my_data = []
for i in range(len(train_data)):
  my_data.append(train_data[i])

run_avg_predictions14 = []
run_avg_x14 = []
mse_errors = []
running_mean = 0.0
for i in range(pred_len):
  run_avg_predictions14.append(running_mean)
decay = 0.5
N = len(my_data)+pred_len-1
for pred_idx in range(1,N):
  running_mean = running_mean*decay + (1.0-decay)*my_data[pred_idx-1]
  run_avg_predictions14.append(running_mean)
  mse_errors.append((run_avg_predictions14[-1]-my_data[pred_idx])**2)
  run_avg_x14.append(date)

my_data = run_avg_predictions14

print('MSE error: %.5f'%(0.5*np.mean(mse_errors)))
```

And the `train_data` look something like this:

```
0      0.959707
1      0.959707
2      0.948718
3      0.959707
4      0.967033
         ...   
295    0.648352
296    0.769231
297    0.868132
298    0.956044
299    0.989011
Length: 300, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Please include the full error traceback.

Comment: `pred_idx` goes from `1` to `N`. `N` is `len(my_data) + pred_len - 1`. `pred_len` is `20`. Then you try to access `my_data[pred_idx]`. The only way that cannot raise an `IndexError` is if `pred_len` were `0`.

Comment: @Paul M. That actually make sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you didn't upload the error itself, I can only guess. But I think your problem is in this line:

```
N = len(my_data)+pred_len-1
for pred_idx in range(1,N):
running_mean = running_mean*decay + (1.0-decay)*my_data[pred_idx-1]
```

Your adding pred_len to the length of my_data, and than substracting one. But than you're calculating the running mean, using my_data[pred_idx-1] which goes up to the number N, which could be out of bounds. So it looks like you're multiplying with something that's not in the list anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You should define `train_data` before this line:

```
line : for i in range(len(train_data)):
```

Answer (score 0):

You forget the pred_idx-1 on the line

```
  mse_errors.append((run_avg_predictions14[-1]-my_data[pred_idx-1])**2)
```